# Add previous responses to form

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs-api

I am creating a sign up sheet where people list what they will bring to an event.  I would like to modify a Section Header at the start of the form that shows who has signed up to bring what, (pulled from the spreadsheet that collect the data) such that people can see what is already being brought to the event.  I am trying to set this on the "On Open" event such that each time the form is loaded people can see other's responses.

I can connect to the spreadsheet via SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet() and then get the data.  I thought I could add the info from the spreadsheet to the section header when the form is being opened.   When I open the form it does not seem to execute this code:

```
function onFormLoad() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  var items = form.getItems();
  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++){
    if (items[i].getType() == FormApp.ItemType.SECTION_HEADER){
      items[i].setTitle("Yes");
      items[i].setHelpText("This is where I want to put the data...");
    }
  }
}
```

If I run this code from the editor it does indeed add the section header.  I need it to run when others open the form.

Answer (score 0):

You should add this code in the onFormSubmit event, you can learn more about the various events here https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_events.

If I am not mistaken, you will need to add the trigger explicitly, read more about triggers here : https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_triggers